# GOLANG bufio Scanner handling 10000 characters

Tags: go, input

I want to input 10000 length of string from os.stdin
but bufio.NewScanner can only read 4096 of characters
How can I read more than 4096 characters?

Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    buf := make([]byte, 2048*2048)
    sc.Buffer(buf, 2048*2048)

    sc.Scan()
    s := sc.Bytes()
    fmt.Println(len(s)) // 9998; must be 10000
    
    str := make([]byte, len(s) + 1)
    for i := 1; i < len(s) + 1; i++ {
        str[i] = s[i-1]
    }
}
```

if I input 10000 characters

panic: runtime error: index out of range [9998] with length 9998

Comment: The `bufio.MaxScanTokenSize` is 64k. It is reading 4096 characters, because that is all it is getting from stdin.

Comment: So I fized my code to increase my buffer size But it still throws error index out of range [9998]

Comment: without for loop len(s) returns 9998

Comment: Can you share your input string?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but I suspect that the missing two characters are the `CR`+`LF` pair used by windows as a line terminator.

This works for me. I'm using a text file ("pp1.txt") that contains the text of Jane Austin's *Pride and Prejudice* broken up into 10,000-character lines — making each line (on my MacOS system) actually 10,001 characters (10,000 characters of text, followed by a `LF` line delimiter). It reads the entire line, discarding the line terminator and giving me 10,000 characters.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("./pp1.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    one_megabyte := 1024 * 1024
    buf := make([]byte, one_megabyte)
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    sc.Buffer(buf, one_megabyte)

    sc.Scan()
    s := sc.Bytes()
    fmt.Println(len(s)) // 9998; must be 10000

    str := make([]byte, len(s)+1)
    for i := 1; i < len(s)+1; i++ {
        str[i] = s[i-1]
    }

}
```

I'm a little confused by this, though:

> ```
> str := make([]byte, len(s)+1)
> for i := 1; i < len(s)+1; i++ {
>   str[i] = s[i-1]
> }
> ```

If you trying to convert the bytes from the scanner into a string, why wouldn't you just use [`sc.Text()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Text) instead of [`sc.Bytes()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Bytes).

Comment: The code was written to solve the algorithm